# conditionally exclude fields from rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The functionality I want to achieve with this is to have different fields based on the action the user is currently on.

The generic scaffold bundles the form into a partial and renders it in the *new* and *edit* actions. In a typical signup case, one may not want to update the password everytime the profile is updated. One way I used to solve this in the past is to create separate forms for *new* and *edit*; including the password in new only. Obviously, most fields repeat themselves. Is there a way to keep the partial but omit (thereby not updating) some fields on the form per action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me assume you are building the form for user model.So in controller you will have

```
def new 
  @user = User.new 
  .....
end 

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ....
end
```

In the form partial use

```
<% if @user.new_record? %>
 <%= f.field_type :field_name %>
<% end %>
```

This will not render the field during edit/update.

Comment: all methods yield the desired result but I like this because no extra variables are added and it doesn't expose the params hash to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way in one partial:

```
<% if params[:action] == "new" %>
   <%= f.field_type :field_name %>
<% end %>
```

But you should think about the security because this doesnt keep away attackers from adding POST fields manually to write to fields that aret displayed as Fields on you form!

Comment: Rails will not include the params of  any field that is not in the form when POSTing the request. Not so sure but I think this is what CSRF is for. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the active record object being passed to the view (such as @user) is a new record or and old one using the method 'new_record?'. Based on this, you can decide what fields you want to display. 
Alternatively, you could also have a partial and then pass it some value (most likely a Boolean) and based on that value you can decide which fields to render. 
This can been done like:
render :partial => 'partial_name', :locals => {:bool => true}

And then in your partial do

```
<% if bool == true %>
 <%= f.xyz_tag :name %> //whatever field you want
<% end %>
```

Comment: How can you pass some of the form model fields instead of bool? And more specifically how do you pass a field of one of many objects in a collection that are rendered with fields_for and (using `accept_nested_attributes_for`)?